# Phaser.io - Is it possible to move tileSprite.tilePosition to a particular target with a tween?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am creating a simple slot machine and currently using TileSprite to achieve the effects that I want - for the spinning. So far, everything works. However, after the timer stops the initial spin, I want to smoothly scroll the texture to the correct 'result' position:

```
R1TimerTrigger: function()
{
    R1Scroll = false;
    game.add.tween(SpriteReel[0].tilePosition).to( { y: R1Result }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.Out, false);
}
```

There are some immediate problems, in that apparently the native tween does not recognize properties of children. Is there a way to solve this, or an alternative approach that does not use tween to achieve the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code looks fine to me and the tween should work on the tile sprite as expected.

Are you starting the tween? You can start the tween automatically using 'true' as the 'autoStart' parameter

```
to(properties, duration, ease, autoStart, delay, repeat, yoyo) 

game.add.tween(SpriteReel[0].tilePosition).to( { y: R1Result }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Bounce.Out, true);
```

Working example here https://phaser.io/sandbox/edit/iTLritEj
Look in the Play and Create tabs

Comment: Doh! Thanks! I just added that to the working system, and it's almost perfect. Just have to choose the ease type.